# fires more then one query in mysql_query

Tags: mysql

```
$updateStock = "UPDATE opening SET qtyUsed = 1000 WHERE openingId = 1 ; UPDATE purchase SET qtyUsed = qtyUsed + 25 WHERE purchaseId = 1";

$updateAllStock = mysql_query($updateStock);
```

This Gives Error : `Data Not InsertedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE purchase SET qtyUsed = qtyUsed + ' at line 3`

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query can only execute one query at a time. You need to execute mysql_query twice.

Instead of the mysql extension use mysqli. With mysqli you can execute multiple queries. http://www.php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.multi-query.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqli_query()
It allows multiple statements. Be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending two queries, so you have to query the databsae twice. There is the support for multiple queries in mysqli, but I strongly advise against using this feature, because you raise the probability of SQL injection attacks.

```
$updateStock = "UPDATE opening SET qtyUsed = 1000 WHERE openingId = 1";
$updatePurchase = "UPDATE purchase SET qtyUsed = qtyUsed + 25 WHERE purchaseId = 1";

$updateAllStock = mysql_query($updateStock);
$updateAllPurchase = mysql_query($updatePurchase);
```

Comment: dear it can be multiple quires more then 25 then what to do ?